# What is the shortest way to insert 2 dashes into this string with ruby?

Tags: ruby

Here's the string: 04046955104021109

I need it to be formatted like so: 040469551-0402-1109

What's the shortest/most efficient way to do that with ruby?

Comment: Shortest in lines of code, or most efficient as in quickest to execute?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two simple inserts will work just fine:

```
example_string.insert(-9, '-').insert(-5, '-')
```

The negative numbers mean that you are counting from the end of the string. You could also count from the beginning if you'd like:

```
example_string.insert(9, '-').insert(14, '-')
```

Comment: It's worth noting this is a modifying method. After running either of these lines `example_string` is now `'040469551-0402-1109'`, not the original `'04046955104021109'`. I'm actually a little surprised the method name isn't `insert!`.

Answer (score 6):

how about

```
s = "04046955104021109"
"#{s[0,9]}-#{s[9,4]}-#{s[13, 4]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little script to show the match:

```
pattern = /\A(\d*?)(\d{4})(\d{4})\Z/

s = "04046955104021109"

output = s.gsub(pattern,'\1-\2-\3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I think Regexp's are overused, and actually I kind of like [Harpastum](http://Harpastum)'s solution, but for the record...

```
>> s = '04046955104021109'
>> s.sub /(....)(....)$/, '-\1-\2'
=> "040469551-0402-1109"
```